# nodejs call an API and return that in a response

Tags: node.js, request, restify

I am very new to nodejs, and I am using restify to create routes, and one of the routes, I call another API, whose response I want to send back.

```
server.get({path:'/admin'},
            function respond(req, res, next){
            var options = { method: 'GET',
                  url: argv.OKTA + "/api/v1/apps/" + argv.OKTA_APP_ID,
                  headers:
                   { authorization: argv.OKTA_API,
                     'content-type': 'application/json',
                     accept: 'application/json' } };

            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) throw new Error(error);

                res.send(200, body);
                return next();
            });

});
```

So, if a GET is done on the /admin path, it should go and call another URL, and get the response back and use that as a response back to the /admin

Right now, I get this instead:

```
{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/admin does not exist"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending a response, you should not call `next()` (that calls the next middleware, which will end up at your 404 middleware).